# send request from node js to shell expect

Tags: node.js, shell, scripting, expect, child-process

about interaction of expect and nodejs.
how can send request from nodejs, to script like that:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect 
log_user 0
spawn -noecho ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no HOST_IP -- "some request"
expect "password: "
send "PASSWORD\r"
expect eof
send_user "$expect_out(buffer)"
```

i need to send a request with special parameters from nodejs, and receive it on expect side?
i make a request from node in this way.

```
var spawn = require('child_process).spawn;
var listA = spawn('./SOME_SHELL_SCRIPT');
```

There is a variant to  add parameters to spawn like this:

```
var listA = spawn('/.SOME_SHELL_SCRIPT',  args=[], [options])
```

how can i use that options, and take them to expect and use them there at "some request" field?

Comment: So basically: "How do I pass arguments to a subprocess?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

app.js

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var script = spawn("./script.sh", ["A Variable"]);
var stdout= ""

script.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  stdout = stdout + data;
});

script.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
});
```

script.sh

```
echo "Script Got '$1'"
```

trying it out:

```
> node app.js
  stdout: Script Got 'A Variable'
```

Comment: I was reading the documentation, I think the event should be `script.on('close',...), not 'exit'`